# Bentley-Ottmann algorithm: swap operation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm in Java, but am stuck at actually implementing the swap operation (see: [Bentley-Ottmann on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm#Detailed_algorithm)) that is needed when processing intersection points.

If I'm understanding the algorithm correctly, there are 3 different types of event points:

1. **Start-point**: This is the leftmost point of a segment, add this segment to the tree and check if it intersects with the segments directly above and below this segment (if they exist)
2. **End-point**: This is the rightmost point of a segment, remove this segment from the tree and check if the segments directly above and below intersect with eachother
3. **Intersection-point**: This is the intersection point of two segments, swap the two segments' positions in the tree [...]

(I'm leaving out a lot of details since they aren't very relevant here)

I'm using a `TreeMap` as my data structure to store my segments. I don't think there is a `swap` operation for `TreeMaps` that lets you just swap two elements, so that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: A TreeMap is sorted, so swap would make no sense, since the order of the elements is always sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes up a lot when people try to implement Bentley-Ottmann. See, for example, [Implementing Bentley–Ottmann Algorithm with an AVL tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243952/implementing-bentley-ottmann-algorithm-with-an-avl-tree) .

tl;dr: You cannot use standard self-balancing binary tree implementations like `TreeMap` for the state structure in Bentley-Ottmann.

When most people use a balanced binary tree like an AVL tree or a Red-Black tree, it's coupled with an immutable ordering over the elements in the tree. 3 is always greater than 2. There will never be a need to swap them. But with Bentley-Ottmann, the ordering is a function of the sweep point, meaning the algorithm needs to directly participate with the tree in reordering elements. In some trees it's possible to hack in a mutable comparator, but even then the only way to convince the tree to rethink its ordering is to remove the element, update the comparator, and re-insert the element -- which is much, much slower than it should be.

Moreover, using a standalone (extrusive) tree structure makes it more difficult to achieve an optimal implementation, because of the frequency with which you directly access elements in the tree. When a line segment ends, you want to go *straight* to that segment's node in the tree in O(1), not meander along the tree to it in O(log n). That means that your Segment structure should serve double-duty as a tree node, not have some way to navigate to the tree node.

So the good news: You get to implement your own balanced binary tree! Have fun. ;-) If you haven't implemented one before, I suggest an [AA tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree). But if you're looking for more of a challenge, and would like a more exotic structure which tends to be a perfect match for Bentley-Ottmann's normal access patterns, try a [Treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap).

Looking in the other direction, if you want to get something working quickly and you don't care about the technical asymptotic bounds, consider just using a linked list for your state structure, locating nodes by a linear scan rather than a tree traversal. In my experience time to locate state nodes is rarely the bottleneck of a Bentley-Ottmann-involving system, and if you're only working with hundreds or thousands of segments, the logarithmic lookups of a binary tree will not be significant.

Comment: Sometimes an upvote isn't enough, and you have make a remark: great answer!

Comment: @BartKiers Happy to hear it :-)

Comment: Oh god, that's what i feared. Thanks for confirming it though!